# How to refer to a nested struct?

Tags: c++, struct, nested

Struct in a struct, how do I call the inner struct?
my current code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int N_ITEMS;
int N_SEATS;

struct ST_SEATS{
struct ITM_TYPE {
   string name;
   float price;       
};
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter number of items: ";
    cin >> N_ITEMS;
    ST_SEATS seat[3];
    seat[1]::ITM_TYPE item[N_ITEMS];
    int i = 0;
    string name = "";
    string input;
    float price;
    while (i < N_ITEMS)
   {
      cout << "Input item name: ";
      cin >> input;
      item[i].name = input;
      cout << "item[" << i << "].name SET" << endl;
      cout << "Input item price: ";
      cin >> price;
      item[i].price = price;
      cout << "item[" << i << "].price SET" << endl;
      i++;
   }
   i = 0;
   while (i < N_ITEMS)
   {
      cout << "item[" << i << "].name = " << item[i].name << endl;
      cout << "item[" << i << "].price = " << item[i].price << endl;
      i++;
   }
   system("pause");
}
```

I am trying to get a receipt maker program that each seat has their own orders, basically.
I know that doesn't relate to the question to well, ask for more info as...Oh the errors i nearly forgot to add

```
21 E:\Documents\School\Computing\SDD\Assign#2\Projects\random.cpp `::ITM_TYPE' has not been declared 

21 E:\Documents\School\Computing\SDD\Assign#2\Projects\random.cpp expected `;' before "item" 

30 E:\Documents\School\Computing\SDD\Assign#2\Projects\random.cpp `item' undeclared (first use this function)
```

Comment: I think SO needs to have line numbering feature

Comment: What do you mean by 'call'? I think you are very confused about what structs are, in the first place, judging by what you seem to be trying to do. You must be sure you understand the difference between types of things, and things that are of that type.

Comment: I want each seat to have a different list of items and prices, I thought embedded struct was the way to do that.
prehaps an embedded loop and nulling the ITM_TYPE stuct (removing the parent stuct to that) would work for item input then seat advancement

Answer (score 2):

The type `ITM_TYPE` exists just once, in the scope of `ST_SEATS`. There's not a different type for each instace of `ST_SEATS`. Therefore the correct way to define an array of it is

```
ST_SEATS::ITM_TYPE item[N_ITEMS];
```

Note, however, that your struct `ST_SEATS` is actually empty (it doesn't contain any members). It only acts as a namespace. Therefore you should replace it by a namespace:

```
namespace ST_SEATS
{
  struct ITM_TYPE
  {
    string name;
    float price;       
  };
}
```

Well, I now notice that you actually define an array of 3 `ST_SEATS`, but that array is not used at all. I now suspect that you probably expected to have your `ITM_TYPE` array as *member* of `ST_SEATS`. But in that case, you have to declare such a member directly in the struct definition.

Also I now notice that your array size is a variable. That's not possible in C++ (some compilers offer it as extension for local arrays, though). Therefore I now think what you *actually* want is:

```
#include <vector>

struct ST_SEATS{
  struct ITM_TYPE {
    string name;
    float price;       
  };
  std::vector<ITM_TYPE> items; // a vector is basically a dynamic array
};

int main()
{
  cout << "Enter number of items: ";
  cin >> N_ITEMS;
  ST_SEATS seat[3];
  seat[1].items.resize(N_ITEMS);
  std::string name = "";
  std::string input;
  float price;
  for (int i=0; i < N_ITEMS; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "Input item name: ";
    std::cin >> input;
    seat[1].items[i].name = input;
    std::cout << "item[" << i << "].name SET" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Input item price: ";
    std::cin >> price;
    seat[1].item[i].price = price;
    std::cout << "item[" << i << "].price SET" << std::endl;
  }

  for (int i=0; i < N_ITEMS; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "item[" << i << "].name = " << seat[1].items[i].name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "item[" << i << "].price = " << seat[1].items[i].price << std::endl;
  }
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: can i use namespaces like    
    namespace SEAT[i]
?

Comment: @Arcticfoxx: No. But you didn't actually use that array anyways (except for defining your `item` array), therefore I didn't really notice it when originally writing my answer. See my edit for what I now think you really want.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
ST_SEATS::ITM_TYPE st_seats;
```

Comment: that works fine thank you but I need ST_SEATS to be variable like ITM_TYPE is

Comment: then use typeof or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

`seat[1]` is not a type. Access the inner type trough `ST_SEATS::ITM_TYPE`.

Note: With C++11 features enabled you could have also said `decltype(seat[1])::ITM_TYPE`.